# Is it possible to create pure CSS class for solving this question in modern browser(IE8+, FF3+, Chrome 3+ and etc.)?

Tags: css

[alt text http://img297.imageshack.us/img297/7632/cssmu.png](http://img297.imageshack.us/img297/7632/cssmu.png)

From the above picture, I have 3 CSS classes() for using in this layout.

*parent* for Black box class

```
.parent
{
   width: 1000px;
   height: 90px;
}
```

*big* for Red box class

```
.big
{
   width: 200px;
   height: 90px;
}
```

*small* forYellow box class

```
.small
{
   width: 200px;
   height: 30px;
}
```

HTML for Figure 1 should be like this.

```
<div class="parent">
   <div class="big"></div>
   <div class="big"></div>
   <div class="small"></div>
   <div class="small"></div>
   <div class="small"></div>
   <div class="big"></div>
   <div class="small"></div>
</div>
```

And HTML for Figure 2 should be like this.

```
<div class="parent">
   <div class="big"></div>
   <div class="big"></div>
   <div class="small"></div>
   <div class="small"></div>
   <div class="big"></div>
   <div class="small"></div>
   <div class="small"></div>
</div>
```

Is it possible to create pure CSS class for solving this problem without modify any tag in HTML?

**Thanks,**

Comment: You might have more luck over at http://doctype.com/

Answer (score 0):

Yes, if you are certain of all the dimensions (i.e. they don't need to adjust dynamically based on their content), this is all very simple using absolute positioning:

```
.parent > * {
  position: absolute;
}

.big {
  top: 0;
}

.big + .big {
  left: 200px;
}

.big + .small {
  top: 0;
}

.big + .big + .small {
  left: 400px;
}

.big + .big + .small + .small {
  top: 30px;
  left: 400px;
}

.big + .big + .small + .small + .small {
  top: 60px;
  left: 400px;
}

.small + .big {
  left: 600px;
}

.small + .big + .small {
  left: 800px;
}

.small + .big + .small + .small {
  top: 30px;
  left: 800px;
}
```

But I don't recommend it as a robust solution in most cases. If you have a little more control of the HTML, and can add some containing `div`s around your `.small`s, you could do something much more robust and flexible using floats.

Comment: I think you miss understand my question. I do not want to fix position of any box from my figure 1 + 2 are just example for using this style. Therefore, it is possible to move small box to first position or move big box to last position.